# Editing a simple curve

Tags: bezier-curves

This is such a dumb question, I'm embarrassed to ask - but I cannot figure out how to modify this simple shape.

The shape comprises a 'fancy' head and tail connected by two straight segments.

All I want to do is add a control point to each of the straight segments so that they can deform along the x-axis - but the deformation should only affect the middle bit. The parts above and below the dashed lines would be unaffected by the deformation.

The parameters for deforming the respective straight sections gets more complicated, and I've added an example of some unacceptable deformations, but really that's a question for another day...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to separate each loose part of your curve because right now you have some control points on top of each other which makes them hard to grab.

First select one of the vertical bars's vertices.

While still hovering over one of its control points, press L to also select the other one.

Right click > Set spline type > Bezier

Right click > Subdivide > Press  <kbd>F9</kbd>  (or expand the foldout in the bottom left of the screen) > choose 3

Now you have a 3 control points between the top one and the bottom one.

Select the two control points closer to the middle (but not the middle one). 
Click on "control points" > set handle type (shortcut  <kbd>V</kbd> ) > Toggle Free / Align . Now these control points will stay in place.

Select the middle control point >  <kbd>V</kbd>  > Aligned

Up the "resolution preview" in the curve settings to 16 or so.

Now when you move the middle control point along the x axis, you will have the desired effect. Play with the scale of each control point (Select >  <kbd>S</kbd>  to scale ) in order to control the falloff of the displacement. Do the same for the other bar.

You might need to make the intermediate control points go lower or higher depending on where you want the curve to begin

I'd recommend using a mirror modifier along y axis.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I'll give this a go, and it might be enough for me to figure out the rest - but just to note that this doesn't (yet) quite fulfil the brief; only the section between the dotted lines is allowed to deform

Comment: I've updated my answer, is it better ?

Comment: Thanks - that's working now. Having done it, I realise that the real problem is considerably more complicated (I just wasn't thinking). Nevertheless, this provides a huge step forward in my technical knowledge. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use only *Bezier curves* for the whole shape.
You can use the handles to adjust the faloff - sharp/gradual.

[image]

Here is the .blend
*(updated 16:40 - matched more precisely to the original + works properly with bevel)*

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks - I just can't seem to get the precise geometry using only beziers